# Doctrine 2 - How to remove one related entity and set to null others?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity-relationship, foreign-key-relationship

I have following entities in my database:

```
class Product
{
    // ...
    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Feature", mappedBy="product")
     **/
    private $features;
    // ...
}

class Feature
{
    // ...
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="features")
     * @JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $product;
    // ...
}
```

In my database, I have one product entity and related to it many features. This is example, but for some reasons I need to remove Product entity and simultaneously set to NULL fields "product_id" in features entity which were assigned to the deleted object.

It is possible to do that calling only `$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->remove($product)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

edit your entity mapping:

```
class Feature
{
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="features")
     * @JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="set null")
     **/
    private $product;
}
```

now, update your schema

Comment: I prefer use upper case **onDelete="SET NULL"**